# Dynamic & Responsive Trapezoid Text Div

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm stuck on a special design, I need to get this effect, keeping in mind that the text could be changed (since it's a wordpress website) to be on one or many lines.
http://postimg.org/image/ibqntp9t1/
I achieved this effect using pseudo elements and here is my code :
CSS:

```
    .box {
        background-color: #000;
    } 
    .box:before {
        content:'';
        border-top: 100px solid transparent;
        border-right: 28px solid #000;
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        left: -13px;
    }
```

The problem is that when the content changes (example: one line of text), the height of the "before" thing does not change ...
Any help ? Thanks

EDIT: Solution provided below isn't working properly (not even working on firefox)

Comment: What effect are you talking about? the slanted edge of the black box?

Comment: Yes exactly, I need it to by dynamic...

Comment: Dynamic meaning....it adjusts to the width of the text?

Comment: to the width and height if possible look at this example: http://postimg.org/image/5b3674uqj/

Comment: Solution is in answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do all the values in `em` then the pseudo-element border triangle will react to changes in font size.

```css
.box {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0 2em;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.box:before {
  content: '';
  border: 1em solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #000;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.larger {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Standard</div>
<div class="box larger">I'm larger</div>
```

Building on the excellent answer from @Stewartside, the clip path can be applied to the pseudo-element.

```css
.box {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0 2em;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.larger {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.box:before {
  content: '';
  background: inherit;
  width: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin-right:-1px; /* tweak due to antialias issue ? */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">lorem</div>
<div class="box larger">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's not working when using more than one line of text...

Comment: What is the difference between the solution Stewartside provided and yours ?

Comment: good shout. +1. I do prefer using P elements or some form of text element though for any text to be displayed for semantic, accessibility and SEO purposes.

Comment: None directly except I use a pseudo-element so the text doesn't get clipped.

Comment: @Stewartside Absolutely, but any block (or inline-block) element would work the same. The div was just for example. a `h1` would work just as well. Good idea with the clip-path.

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah true, just clarifying :)

Comment: How can I get the width proportional with the text inside the container please?

Comment: What do you mean....you want the arrow to be % width of the whole element? Yeah you can do that - http://jsfiddle.net/zof5fjhr/1/

Comment: Thank you. The solution for the slanted edge isn't working on firefox...

Comment: I found a fix for firefox

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with CSS `clip-path` to create the shape. The more lines you add, the higher the shape becomes.

You just need to amend the first part of the `clip-path` to say how far indented the shape is and then amend the `padding` on the `p` tag.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(15% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(15% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
.container p {
  padding-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Test
    <br />test
  </p>
</div>

<br />

<div class="container">
  <p>
    Test
    <br />test
    <br />test
    <br />test
    <br />test
    <br />test
    <br />test
  </p>
</div>
```

- [`clip-path` MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)
- [Clip Path Generator](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: How can I get the width proportional with the text inside the container please?

Comment: Remove the width and add `display: inline-block;`. You may want to add some padding to the text or set a minimum width though as it can sometimes look out of shape.

Comment: Ok thanks, the problem now is that your solution does not work on Firefox...